# Spring 2.5 SpringJUnit4ClassRunner can not autowire when tx:annotation-driven is used

Tags: spring, autowired

TestCode

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:transactional/batch/context.xml" })
public class TransactionTest {
@Autowired
TestBatch testBatch;
```

Case 1: 
TestBatch is auto wire to TransactionTest  successfully

context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="testBatch" class="transactional.batch.TestBatch"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Case 2: 
But this case is failed.

context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="testBatch" class="transactional.batch.TestBatch"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: transactional.batch.TestBatch transactional.batch.TransactionTest.testBatch; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [transactional.batch.TestBatch] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [class transactional.batch.TestBatch]: expected at least 1 matching bean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [transactional.batch.TestBatch] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [class transactional.batch.TestBatch]: expected at least 1 matching bean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
    ... 21 more
```

Only difference is `tx:annotation-driven`'s `proxy-target-class` attribute.

Why `tx:annotation-driven` control the auto wire?

Comment: well, seems to me that is not that "tx:annotation-driven control the auto wire". But instead based on the stack the auto-proxied class has the same id `No unique bean of type [transactional.batch.TestBatch]`. Why you don't try via [@Qualifier](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `TestBatch` implements an interface, and has `@Transactional` on some of its methods.

`<tx:annotation-driven>` will generate a transactional proxy object for `TestBatch`. By default, if `TestBatch` implements any interfaces, then this proxy object will implement those interfaces, but will not extend `TestBatch.  If you use`proxyTargetClass`, then the generated proxy object will instead subclass`TestBatch`.

Since your unit test requires the object to be of type `TestBatch`, that means you must use `proxyTargetClass` in your config.  Alternatively, change your unit test so to use one of `TestBatch`'s interfaces, rather than the `TestBatch` type directly.